# how to Calculate SHA3-256 for every file in js?

Tags: hash, readfile, cryptojs

I have many data file inside *data* folder . i just read one of them which is returning 64 hex code smth like that *f0bef0fedb9a235b0b559f2749f9e6ce6405761b784747be51041c6610232896*. How can i loop through each file inside *data folder* and return 64 hex code? and also there some other requirements:
Write hashes as 64 hex digits in lower case.
Sort hashes as strings.
Join sorted hashes without any separator.
Concatenate resulted string with your e-mail.
Here is my starting code :

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
import fs from 'fs'
const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./data/file_00.data')
console.log(fileBuffer);
const hash = crypto.createHash("SHA3-256")
const finalHex = hash.update(fileBuffer).digest("hex")
console.log(finalHex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('./data/');
for(const fName of fileNames) {
   const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`./data/${fName}`);
   //Calculate hash for every file here.
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks. but how can i sort those hashes as string and join them without  any seperator?

Answer (score 0):

For sorting and joining, outside of the for loop above you could declare an array...

```
const finalHexes = [];
```

After computing a `finalHex`, add it to the array...

```
finalHexes.push(finalHex);
```

Then sort and join using an empty string to eliminate the separator.

```
const sortedAndJoined = finalHexes.sort().join('');
```